# How to dynamicaly call void configure(HttpSecurity http) in Spring Security Framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

All http security is applied at startup in Spring Framework. During runtime, I am trying to add more Role and User for Spring security. How Can I Update the security configuration during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of updating your security configuration during runtime, you should configure it in a more flexible way at start up. for your use case i think it's better to go for `Spring Security` `UserDetailsService`. [This is a tutorial link that might be helpful.](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database)

Comment: thank you for your answer. i will follow the tutorial.